# Create jar of a class in order to send objects JAVA

Tags: java, eclipse, class, jar

I would like to know how to create a jar, usable by other java programs.
To be clearer I want to send an object to a client. There is a program client and another that plays the server. One creates the obect and the other reads it.

I have my class already done and I know it work well. But I can't just copy paste my class in both programs (I learned that the bad way). 
So I know that I need a .jar with my class in it.

I managed to create my .jar, add it as an external jar, import it with **import com.classe.object.topic;**, and it is reconized by both programs but when I need my constructor. It doesn't seem to work.

```
    package com.classe.object.topic;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class ObjectToSend implements Serializable {


    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7934480991083114348L;

    String prenom;
      String nom;
      int idGloreg;
      int indPerso; 
      boolean ok;
      String entite;
      int error;


    ObjectToSend(String prenomP, String nomP, int idGloregP, int indPersoP, boolean okP, String entiteP, int errorP){
           prenom = prenomP ;
           nom= nomP;
          idGloreg = idGloregP;
           indPerso = indPersoP; 
           ok = okP;
           entite= entiteP;
           error = errorP;  
      }


    }
```

This is what I want to use in both programs but doing

```
new ObjectToSend("pro", "enc", 134, 10, true, "Tam", 0);
```

Eclipse tells me that he can't find my constructor. Can somebody explain me how to do this or give me a tutorial. That would be really great.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constructor in your class isn't public, so [it is impossible to see it outside its own package](http://javapapers.com/core-java/access-modifiers-in-java-explain/), add the `public` keyword to your constructor and you may be able to see it:

```
public class ObjectToSend implements Serializable {
    [...]
    public ObjectToSend(String prenomP, String nomP, int idGloregP, int indPersoP, boolean okP, String entiteP, int errorP){
       prenom = prenomP ;
       nom= nomP;
      idGloreg = idGloregP;
       indPerso = indPersoP; 
       ok = okP;
       entite= entiteP;
       error = errorP;  
  }
}
```

Comment: Indeed, it was that thanks a lot. I was looking so far away, it was actually really simple. I also didn't do setter and getter.
I forgot that in java not expliciting the modifier is like saying private.